# API awaited Fetch Ignores FlowListView Setter

Tags: c#, xamarin.forms

The code to set my Flowlist is getting ignored, But only on the first instance the page opens.

```
    protected override async void OnAppearing()
        {
                    WCObject WooObject = new WCObject(rest);
                    //This Runs Fine 
                    var Tags = await WooObject.Tag.GetAll(new Dictionary<string, string>() {
                    { "per_page", "100" } });
                    //This Doesnt Run
                    Taglistview.FlowItemsSource = Tags;
                    //Runs fine after you Reopen the page 
        }
```

Same Result's on my Init Task. I'm trying to understand Async and await and Where to use it, But this is over my head. I think its waiting for the Get all Thread to Finish but  why? There is no wait()

Here's the Stack trace its the only error occurring

```
RestAPI.SendHttpClientRequest[T] (System.String endpoint, WooCommerceNET.RequestMethod method, T requestBody, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parms)
```

```
System.Net.WebException: System.Net.WebException
```

```
WooCommerceNET
RestAPI.SendHttpClientRequest[T] (System.String endpoint, WooCommerceNET.RequestMethod method, T requestBody, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parms)
WooCommerceNET
RestAPI.GetRestful (System.String endpoint, System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parms)
WooCommerceNET.Base
WCItem`1[T].GetAll (System.Collections.Generic.Dictionary`2[TKey,TValue] parms)
```

Comment: What is WCObject? What is the return Tags value?

Comment: Its a API object a List of Json That just gets Serialized into a list

Comment: You can get all data into Tags? Can you try to add await Task.Delay() to get all data from api.

Comment: This was weird it endedup just resolving its self after a day but I will try that and yes Tags do get the appropriate data

Comment: It seems that you have solved your issue now? If yes, please remember to share your solution for reply and mark your reply as answer, thanks.

Comment: Thing is i'm actually not sure how it got fixed it just started working